# No soap.so PHP module file after installing SOAP

Tags: php, soap, centos

I have an issue where, after installing SOAP for PHP 5.3, I have no 
/usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so file on my system and can therefor not use native SOAP.

What am I missing? I have --enable-soap=shared set as you can see below.

When I run the following command on my CentOS VM running PHP 5.3.10:

```
[root@dev53 ~]# php -i | grep configure
```

I get this:

> Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu'
>   '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu'
>   '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr'
>   '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc'
>   '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include'
>   '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec'
>   '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/usr/com'
>   '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info'
>   '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--with-libdir=lib64'
>   '--with-config-file-path=/etc'
>   '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d' '--disable-debug'
>   '--with-pic' '--disable-rpath' '--without-pear' '--with-bz2'
>   '--with-exec-dir=/usr/bin' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr'
>   '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf'
>   '--without-gdbm' '--with-gettext' '--with-gmp' '--with-iconv'
>   '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl' '--with-zlib'
>   '--with-layout=GNU' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp'
>   '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvsem'
>   '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--with-kerberos'
>   '--enable-ucd-snmp-hack' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-calendar'
>   '--without-sqlite' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--enable-xml'
>   '--with-system-tzdata' '--enable-force-cgi-redirect' '--enable-pcntl'
>   '--with-imap=shared' '--with-imap-ssl' '--enable-mbstring=shared'
>   '--enable-mbregex' '--with-gd=shared' '--enable-bcmath=shared'
>   '--enable-dba=shared' '--with-db4=/usr' '--with-xmlrpc=shared'
>   '--with-ldap=shared' '--with-ldap-sasl' '--with-mysql=shared,/usr'
>   '--with-mysqli=shared,/usr/lib64/mysql/mysql_config'
>   '--enable-dom=shared' '--with-pgsql=shared' '--enable-wddx=shared'
>   '--with-snmp=shared,/usr' '**--enable-soap=shared**'
>   '--with-xsl=shared,/usr' '--enable-xmlreader=shared'
>   '--enable-xmlwriter=shared' '--with-curl=shared,/usr'
>   '--enable-fastcgi' '--enable-pdo=shared'
>   '--with-pdo-odbc=shared,unixODBC,/usr'
>   '--with-pdo-mysql=shared,/usr/lib64/mysql/mysql_config'
>   '--with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/usr' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared,/usr'
>   '--with-pdo-dblib=shared,/usr' '--without-sqlite3'
>   '--enable-json=shared' '--enable-zip=shared' '--with-readline'
>   '--with-pspell=shared' '--enable-phar=shared'
>   '--with-mcrypt=shared,/usr' '--with-tidy=shared,/usr'
>   '--with-mssql=shared,/usr' '--enable-sysvmsg=shared'
>   '--enable-sysvshm=shared' '--enable-sysvsem=shared'
>   '--enable-posix=shared' '--with-unixODBC=shared,/usr'
>   '--enable-fileinfo=shared' '--enable-intl=shared'
>   '--with-icu-dir=/usr' '--with-recode=shared,/usr'

Comment: Strangely, I still don't have a soap.so file - however after running these commands below I now have SOAP installed and can use native SOAP. I hope this is of use to someone.


    cd /var/tmp
    
    wget http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/x86_64/php-soap-5.3.10-1.w5.x86_64.rpm
    
    rpm -ivh php-soap-5.3.10-1.w5.x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following commands on CentOS to resolve:

```
cd /var/tmp 
wget http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/x86_64/php-soap-5.3.10-1.w5.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh php-soap-5.3.10-1.w5.x86_64.rpm
```